# How do I flush output to a zenity progress bar in fish shell

Tags: shell, fish, zenity

In bash I can run the following to get a progress bar for long running processes

```
for i in $(seq 90 100); do 
  echo $i; 
  sleep 1; 
done | zenity --progress
```

However if I attempt the same thing in fish shell, the loop blocks and doesn't flush output down to zenity until it's finished:

```
for i in (seq 90 100)
  echo $i
  sleep 1
end | zenity --progress
```

How would I create a similar progress box in fish shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fish currently buffers all output belonging to functions and blocks, so:

You don't.